# How can I copy text from Exceed?

Tags: copy-paste, exceed

How can I copy text from an open X window (XTerm, Gvim, etc) in Hummingbird Exceed running on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

On OpenText Exceed 14 (which I understand was formerly Hummingbird Exceed) you can cut and paste from X to Windows by,

1. Highlight desired text in X window
2. Right click on Exceed icon in the Task Bar
3. Select from pop-up menu `Edit` | `Copy X selection` | `To clipboard`
4. Paste into your Windows application in the normal way (`Edit | Paste` or `CTL+V`)

Similarly you can copy/paste from Windows to X by selecting `Edit` | `Paste to X selection` | `From clipboard`.

I've found this to be very reliable, whereas just using only the usual copy/paste options on X and Windows sides often doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that was easier for me was to configure an auto copy to clipboard setting.

Open `Start Menu > All Programs > OpenText Exceed > Exceed Tools > XConfig`.

Go to: `X Selection`, and change it to `PRIMARY` and make sure the `Auto copy` feature is checked.

Click `Validate and Apply Changes` (green check mark) and you are done.

No when you select anything in the linux windows, it should go to the clipboard, and you can just press Ctrl-V when you are back in Windows and it will work.

Hope that helps.