# How to paste from Local Windows 7 to Hummingboard Exceed

Tags: windows-7, x-windows, exceed

Exceed - 14.0.8.584
Windows7

I am able to copy from Xwindows to my local desktop however I am not able to PASTE from windows7 to Exceed. I need the converse of [How can I copy text from Exceed?](https://superuser.com/questions/204482/how-can-i-copy-text-from-exceed). I tried going to the Edit menu in the taskbar icon and `Paste to X selection -> From clipboard` but nothign happens

On XConfig -> Copy and Paste X-Selection I have checked all "Auto-copy and copy checkboxes" for PRIMARY, SECONDARY etc.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the problem could be your x-selection is not associated with your clipboard. Make sure its set to clipboard

x-config -> X selection -> choose CLIPBOARD from the list.

That fixed my issue. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

To copy from Windows 7 to Exceed highlight the text on the windows side and copy it with cntrl+c. Then just click in the exceed window and use the middle click button on the mouse to paste your selection.